# GraphQL Unkown argument "price_gt" on field of type Query

Tags: mongodb, graphql, mongodb-atlas

With MongoDBAtlas I am trying to query products in my database which are greater than a certain price. Here is my query:

```
query findProducts{
  product(price_gt: 2000)
  {
            id,
            price
          }
    }
```

Here is the structure of the query:

```
product(query: ProductQueryInput): Product
```

Here is the relevant extract of my GraphQL schema:

```
input ProductQueryInput {
    price_gt: String
}
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"price_gt\" on field \"product\" of type \"Query\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 33,
          "column": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi type of price_gt is string and you pass a number for it .try to pass as string like "200"

Comment: I am aware of this, it didn't make a difference when directly querying the database through db.connect. The error is coming from the price_gt element, before it reaches the input value.